# Would tags for "event" and/or "residence" be helpful?

Tags: discussion, tags

See the question, [Census or Residence](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/census-or-residence); it inquires about whether a census is an "event" or if it is a series of underlying "pfacts" (age/inferred dob, residence, occupation, etc.).

We have a tag for census-records, do we need tags for the related concepts of "events" and even more specifically for "residence." etc.?

Comment: My first thought is that "event" is way too broad. It won't be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with a comment on the question by @AmericanLuke:

> My first thought is that "event" is way too broad. It won't be very
>   helpful.

However, the term [`residence` turns up in quite a few questions](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/search?q=residence%20is%3Aquestion) so I *think* it could be useful.

I use frequency of terms being used as a proxy (and very rough) measure for whether they might be useful as tags.  For me terms that could be used on too many or too few Q&As make poor tags for SE sites.

I can foresee our users filtering questions using it to expand their understanding of what `residence` means to genealogists and family historians when thinking about things like:

- What is a residence?
- What is a residence event to a software package and GEDCOM?
- How to find a residence for someone between census collections?

These could be found by simply searching on the term but that wide net may lead to opening Q&As where residence is an aside rather than central.  By tagging the subset of questions where the term is important we can quickly distinguish Q&As about residence from those that merely mention it.

Comment: As I write this, we have 1,137 questions, of which 45 have the word residence.  The term is common and is likely to turn up all over the place.  The frequency of the term is not the only guide -- my question is, will the ability to tag a question with 'residence' allow us to distinguish questions where determining someone's residence is the core problem from all the other questions that merely mention it?

Answer (score -1):

I feel "event" and "residence" are both very broad / generic that wouldn't bring a lot of value. Instead of residence I would use the more commonly used "address", or "property-records" depending on the question. There are also some other location based mapping tags like "GIS" already in use as well.

Comment: A business (which is not usually a residence) can have an address so I think residence and address should not be synonyms. And GIS is a very distinct topic from residence and far broader.